# Does multiple selector work with :hover?

Tags: html, css

I want after hover change style for left and right arrow how can I do that?

```
.header-slider .content:hover .left-arrow, .right-arrow
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Test it out with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and you will see...

Comment: i know that it don't work. but there is must be a way to do it like this i know that i can do on that way ".header-slider .content:hover .left-arrow, .header-slider .content:hover .right-arrow"  but I dont want to do on that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, but really, it's better to just write out the long selector.

```
.header-slider .content:hover [class$="-arrow"]
```

If you want to type less use Sass or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need a better selector:

```
.header-slider .content:hover .left-arrow, .header-slider .content:hover .right-arrow {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If you don't like this way, you can add a common class for arrows, say `.arrow`, and simply do:

```
.header-slider .content:hover .arrow {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Of course, this will require some HTML changes, not purely done in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
.header-slider .content:hover .left-arrow, .header-slider .content:hover .right-arrow {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Your original code is equivalent to

```
.header-slider .content:hover .left-arrow {
    opacity: 1;
}

.right-arrow {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

Which I don't think is what you want.

If you find this too verbose, check out the css preprocessor [sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which allows you to write:

```
.header-slider .content:hover {
    .left-arrow, .right-arrow {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: .header-slider .content:hover .left-arrow, .header-slider .content:hover .right-arrow {
    opacity: 1;
} there no other way to write this code?